# DateIndexer issue

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, sectionindexer

So I have a recent call page. I want to separate my recent calls by the date (in the format MMMM DD, YYYY) but it doesn't show up properly. I only get the first date , December 17th, 2013, to show up even though the last three entries are: December 16th, 2013, December 16th, 2013, and December 13th, 2013.

Here is my code for this:

```
boolean needSeparator = false;

final int position = cursor.getPosition();

if(this.dateIndexer == null)
      this.dateIndexer = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm aa MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
Date testDate;
try {
          testDate = sdf.parse(date);
          Calendar calDate = Calendar.getInstance();
          calDate.setTime(testDate);
          String day = String.valueOf(calDate.get(Calendar.DATE));
          String month = calDate.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
          String year = String.valueOf(calDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
          shortDate = month + " " + day + ", " + year;

          if(!shortDate.equals(prDate)){
              this.dateIndexer.put(shortDate, position);
              prDate = shortDate;
          }
} catch (ParseException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
}

    Set<String> sectionDates = this.dateIndexer.keySet();

    // create a list from the set to sort
    ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionDates);

    this.sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
    sectionList.toArray(this.sections);

    if (position == 0) {
       needSeparator = true;
    } else {
       cursor.moveToPosition(position - 1);

       cursor.copyStringToBuffer(RecentQuery.COLUMN_DATE, mBuffer);
       if (mBuffer.sizeCopied > 0 && holder.dateBuffer.sizeCopied > 0 && mBuffer.data[0] != holder.dateBuffer.data[0]) {
           needSeparator = true;
       }

       cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    }

    if (needSeparator) {
       holder.separator.setText(sectionList.get(sectionList.size() - 1));
       holder.separator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
       holder.separator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Any help will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the char buffers to strings and that worked. This if statement

```
if (mBuffer.sizeCopied > 0 && holder.dateBuffer.sizeCopied > 0 && mBuffer.data[0] != holder.dateBuffer.data[0]) {
       needSeparator = true;
}
```

Was only taking the first character into account(Like it should). I used this for my contact page where I was separating by only letters. So changing it to compare strings fixed the issue.

Here is the new code

```
boolean needSeparator = false;

final int position = cursor.getPosition();

if(this.dateIndexer == null)
   this.dateIndexer = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm aa MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
try {
    Calendar calDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    calDate.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
    String day = String.valueOf(calDate.get(Calendar.DATE));
    String month = calDate.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
    String year = String.valueOf(calDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    shortDate = month + " " + day + ", " + year;

    if(!shortDate.equals(prDate)){
       this.dateIndexer.put(shortDate, position);
       prDate = shortDate;
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
holder.dBuffer = shortDate;
Set<String> sectionDates = this.dateIndexer.keySet();

// create a list from the set to sort
ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionDates);

this.sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
sectionList.toArray(this.sections);

        if (position == 0) {
            needSeparator = true;
        } else {
            cursor.moveToPosition(position - 1);

            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm aa MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                Calendar calDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                calDate.setTime(sdf.parse(cursor.getString(RecentQuery.COLUMN_DATE)));
                String day = String.valueOf(calDate.get(Calendar.DATE));
                String month = calDate.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
                String year = String.valueOf(calDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                sBuffer = month + " " + day + ", " + year;

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (sBuffer.length() > 0 && holder.dBuffer.length() > 0 && !sBuffer.equals(holder.dBuffer)) {
                needSeparator = true;
            }

            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        }

        if (needSeparator) {
            holder.separator.setText(String.valueOf(this.sections[this.sections.length - 1]));
            holder.separator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.separator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```